# Where should i get context.xml for tomcat7-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin, embedded-tomcat-7

When i run embedded tomcat with the help of **tomcat7-maven-plugin** it crashes with following 
error:

```
SEVERE: Missing context.xml
```

I have following configuration in maven plugin:

```
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <path>/project_name_test</path>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>tomcat-run</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run-war-only</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <fork>true</fork>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shutdown</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Do we have an option for default context? I don't want to create any context - i have war file which will be uploaded into this application server.

**EDIT:**

I found the issue. In order to ingore context.xml you should add  attribute with  parameters you need. For example :

```
                        <configuration>
                            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                            <server>localhost</server>
                            <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try just this first:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

If you need a context.xml file it should go under META-INF folder.

Comment: what if the difference between my configuration and yours?

Comment: Does it still crash? What do you mean nothing happens? Does it start?

Comment: it just does nothing, in my example there was some exception, in your example tomcat isn't launched. The thing is there is no difference between my example and yours except executions that i use for testing. So, basically, they are just the same.

Comment: I'm using 2.2, not sure that matters. Also, what java version are you using? Since you're using tomcat7 you need at least 6 or later.

Comment: i don't understand how does it matters, i'm using java7 and tomcat7